# Entity framework June 2011 CTP questions

Tags: entity-framework

Supposedly this release includes 2 features I'm interested in.

1. Enums support
2. Model can be broken into multiple files.

I don't want to install it because of issues people report, so I will ask questins here :)

1. Is there any wild guess when we get production-ready version of this stuff?
2. My issue with EF right now is that it get's really slow after 100+ tables. Do I understand correctly that new feature with multiple diagrams will help with scalability?

Comment: When you say EF gets really slow after 100+ tables, are you talking about the Entity Designer itself (as described at http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/entity-framework-designer-and-large-databases/) or runtime query performance?

Comment: Well, really slow is probably too strong but yes, after 100+ tables designer get's slow and uneasy to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Its in EF version 4.1
2. Code first method drops the EDMX designer all together, its all in code using classes, and if a slow designer is a a big thing for you, code first method is definitely for you.